# Django templates: how to concatenate a named URL and a string?

Tags: django, templates

I have the following settings:

The `urls.py` of the project's app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^main/', include('main.urls', namespace='main')),
]
```

The `main` app's `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^add/$', views.add, name='add'),
]
```

I am trying to create an URL as `/main/add/whatever/` in a template, hypothetically as follows:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'main:add' %}" + "whatever/">
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'main:add' %}whatever/">
```

The code inside the curly braces will be rendered by your template system, and will precede the `whatever`, thus generating the following HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/main/add/whatever/">
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I didn't expect it to be so simple. Thanks a lot.