# how to change a url to a path on django

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I have been trying to make a like | dislike button on django but the problem I have is that a 404 error pops up because I am using path but the code I am learning from is using url, so can someone help me changing this url to path?

```
    url(r'^(?P<postid>\d+)/preference/(?P<userpreference>\d+)/$', postpreference, name='postpreference'),
```

I tryed to change it to path but still didn't worked

```
    path('posts/<int:postid>/preference/<int:userpreference>', views.postpreference, name='like_post'),
```

Now this is the html that is supposed to like and dislike

```
    <form id="likebutton" method="POST" action="/posts/{{image.id}}/preference/1/">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden">
    </form>

    <form id="dislikebutton" method="POST" action="/posts/{{image.id}}/preference/2/">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden">
    </form>
```

this is my views.py

```
    def postpreference(request, postid, userpreference):
if request.method == 'POST':
    images = get_object_or_404(Post, id=postid)
    obj=""
    valueobj=""
    try:
        obj = Preference.objects.get(user=request.user, post=images)
        valueobj = obj.value 
        userprefence = int(userprefence)

        if valueobj != userprefence:
            obj.delete()

            upre = Preference()
            upref.user = request.user
            upref.post = images
            upref.value = userpreference

            if userpreference == 1 and valueobj != 1:
                images.likes += 1
                images.dislikes -= 1
            elif userpreference == 2 and valueobj != 2:
                images.dislikes += 1
                images.likes -= 1

            upref.save()
            images.save()

            context={'images': images, 'postid': postid}
            return render (request, 'imagelist.html', context)

        elif valueobj == userpreference:
            obj.delete()

            if userpreference == 1:
                images.likes -= 1
            elif userpreference == 2:
                eachpost.dislikes -= 1

            eachpost.save()

            context= {'eachpost': eachpost, 'postid': postid}

            return render (request, 'posts/detail.html', context)

    except Preference.DoesNotExist:
        upref= Preference()

        upref.user= request.user

        upref.post= images

        upref.value= userpreference

        userpreference= int(userpreference)

        if userpreference == 1:
                images.likes += 1
        elif userpreference == 2:
                images.dislikes +=1

        upref.save()

        images.save()                            


        context= {'images': images, 'postid': postid}

        return render (request, 'imagelist.html', context)
else:
    images = get_object_or_404(Post, id=postid)
    context= {'images': images, 'postid': postid}
    return render (request, 'posts/detail.html', context)
```

Comment: You should use the [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag

Comment: You use the `image.id`, whereas in the url you use a `post_id`?

Comment: I just added the views.py

Comment: @IainShelvington How do I use a {% url %} tag with this big url? sorry, I'm new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `lain` suggested, use the [URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tags instead of what you have.

From docs, the structure is as follows

```
{% url 'some-url-name' arg1=v1 arg2=v2 %}
```

So you would need something like this

```
<form id="likebutton" method="POST" action="{% url 'like_post' id=image.id  1/2 %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden">
</form>
```

You can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35382754/6505847) on how you concatenate some other strings to the url.

Comment: The code is now showing a template syntax error TemplateSyntaxError at /imagelist
Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'    What should I do now?

Comment: Yes sorry., I have updated it. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463050/putting-django-passed-variables-inside-url) for some explanation.

Comment: the fact that the preferences are not being used affect the url?

Comment: Sry. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes mmmm well the preferences 1 and 2  I think are the ones that determine if it is disliking or liking and an error will probably pop up again because in the {% url '' %}tag there is no preference. I may be wrong.

Comment: Yes I left that for you to add. You can simply add it as `{% url 'like_post' id=image.id 1/2 %}`for the dislike/like for the form tags.

Comment: thankyou!! now, do you know how I can turn the dislike button to just unlike so there is no dislike a dislike button?

Comment: Well, if I understand it correctly, you can do that with jquery. Have a method in Javascript that changes to `unlike` when the `dislike` is pressed. Change, as in replace the entire element in DOM, or simply updates the text.